# UWP, Binding multiple data from listview

Tags: c#, listview, binding, uwp

I'm having trouble with gathering data from multiple selected item from listvew. Let's say I have 10 items, if I select 5 of them, is there a way to store them into some kind of a array or something? My listview is like below:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

Comment: ListView has a SelectedItems property.

Comment: Yea I noticed but when I check its value, I dont remember exacly but its something like system.context. So not the values that I want :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `SelectedItems` property, which is an `IList<object>`. You can enumerate it like this:

```
foreach ( var selectedItem in listView.SelectedItems.OfType<XXX>() )
{
    //do something
}
```

Where `XXX` is the type of collection you bind to the `ListView`.

Furthermore you can use UWP Behaviors to trigger command whenever selection changes. See [this blog post](http://igrali.com/2015/03/06/pass-listview-selecteditems-to-viewmodel-in-universal-apps/) for more details.